# How to "hide" a password in html text input

Tags: html, css, forms

I am currently building a form, where I have a password.

Is a way to maintain the input type as `text` while the password remains "hidden".

So basically instead of this being displayed in the text field:

```
mypassword
```

I want it to say:

```
*********
```

or something close to that. So basically just making the text that the user inputs not to be visible.

I know that changing the type to `password` will be a solution but I need to maintain the type as `text`.

Comment: No, HTML input forms do not behave like this 'natively' - any particular reason you need the type to be 'text'?  I am not sure I follow the use case or need for this

Comment: A keyup event listener could be used to collect characters while replacing them with asterisks but filtering out control keys, such as shift, and accounting for deletions or pasted characters might be tricky.

Comment: Maybe meention in question why you need input tot be type=text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason why this could be useful is temporarily show last entered character as on mobile devices:

```js
function passwordInput(el)
{
  //already initialized?
  if (el.actualValue !== undefined)
    return el;

  let timer = null;
  el.actualValue = el.value;
  el.addEventListener("input", e =>
  {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    const val = el.value,
          start = el.selectionStart,
          end = el.selectionEnd,
          len = val.length - el.actualValue.length,
          //find none-hidden characters
          diff = (val.substring(0, start).match(/[^●]+/g)||[""])[0],
          //this will be shown for nn seconds
          last = diff === "" ? "" : diff[diff.length - 1],
          //replace all characters with hidden character
          vis = "".padStart(val.length, "●");

    //record new value
    el.actualValue = el.actualValue.substring(0, start - diff.length) + diff + el.actualValue.substring(start - len);
    //replace visible value with hidden characters, except for the last "new" character
    el.value = vis.substring(0, start - last.length) + last + vis.substring(start);
    //set cursor back to it's original position
    el.selectionStart = start;
    el.selectionEnd = end;
    //hide entire visible value after nn seconds
    timer = setTimeout(() =>
    {
      const start = el.selectionStart,
            end = el.selectionEnd;

      el.value = vis;
      el.selectionStart = start;
      el.selectionEnd = end;
    }, 1000); // 1 second delay
  });
  if (el.value !== "")
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"))

  return el;
}

passwordInput(document.getElementById("myInput")).addEventListener("input", e =>
{
  //display real value
  output.textContent = e.target.actualValue;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" autocomplete="off">
<div>Actual value: <span id="output"></span><div>
```

Basically, what it does, is store actual value in `inputElement.actualValue` property and replaces value with "●" character. There is one kink I didn't bother to look at, is selection getting reset when last character become hidden.